# Can I replicated 2 SQL Server database with foreign key in some tables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication

Assume I've 15 databases, 1 is main database and another is database located at various site. I need to create replication between main database and another. My fellows have tested replication and they conclude that replication can't working correctly if I've set foreign key on some table.

I try to search on google with this kind of problem, unfortunately I've found nothing. I want to make sure, can I create replication between 2 databases with foreign key in some tables or not? If so, please suggest good resource, may be a book to gain some knowledge about its.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can setup replication with foreign keys on the tables.  Transactions are on the subscriber in the same order that they are committed on the publisher so if you put data in a parent table, then a child it'll be done in the same order on the subscriber.

Comment: Do you have any books or links related to this kind of operation? I need to send it to my fellows. =)

Comment: Look for "How Transactional Replication Works" in Books OnLine.  "Subscribers receive transactions in the same order in which they were applied at the Publisher."